# ¿Cómo agregar números enteros por input del usuario en un array en C#?

Tags: c#

Necesito introducir dos listas de 15 números, cada uno en un array, para posteriormente calcular la suma de cada array y compararlas entre si. He utilizado el siguiente código:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Ejercicio_24_alt
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //VARIABLES

            int[] array1 = new int[15];

            int[] array2 = new int[15];

            int suma1 = 0, suma2 = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Introduce dos lista de 15 valores: ");

            Console.WriteLine("Introduce los datos de la lista 1: ");

            loop(array1, suma1);

            Console.WriteLine("Ahora introduce los datos de la lista 2:");

            loop(array2, suma2);

            if (suma1 > suma2) Console.WriteLine($"La suma de la lista 1 es mayor a la suma de la lista 2.");

            else Console.WriteLine($"La suma de la lista 2  es mayor a la suma de la lista 1.");


        }

        static int loop(int[] array, int suma)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Número {i + 1}: ");

                int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                array.SetValue(num, i);

                //Alternativamente

                // array[i]=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return suma = array.Sum();

        }
    }

}
```

He utilizado alternativamente `array[i]=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` pero tanto de una forma como de otra siempre me devuelve 0 en la suma de cada array. De hecho si se hace `Console.WriteLine(suma1);` después de declarar en el Main el método loop imprime 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en que validas `if (suma1 > suma2)`, pero tus valores para `suma1` y `suma2` siempre son 0, entonces por eso siempre te imprime 0.

Ahora, tu método `static int loop(int[] array, int suma)`, es un método estático que retorna un valor `int` que es el valor de la suma de los valores del arreglo. **Pero lamentablemente ejecutas el método pero no recibes el valor de la suma.**

Arréglalo asignándole las variables ya definidas de `suma1` y `suma2`. Algo como:

```
int[] array1 = new int[15];

int[] array2 = new int[15];

int suma1 = 0, suma2 = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Introduce dos lista de 15 valores: ");

Console.WriteLine("Introduce los datos de la lista 1: ");

suma1 = loop(array1, suma1); //Asigna variable para recibir el valor de la suma

Console.WriteLine("Ahora introduce los datos de la lista 2:");

suma2 = loop(array2, suma2); //Asigna variable para recibir el valor de la suma

if (suma1 > suma2) Console.WriteLine($"La suma de la lista 1 es mayor a la suma de la lista 2.");

else Console.WriteLine($"La suma de la lista 2  es mayor a la suma de la lista 1.");
```

**Te recomiendo hacer uso de los checkpoint para hacer debug a tu código y así puedas identificar los problemas que tengas probando linea por linea.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En programación hay un principio que en esencia dice que un método o una clase solo debe hacer lo que le corresponde y nada más, tu **método loop** solo debe centrarse en llenar el arreglo ya que esta es su única responsabilidad, por lo que la suma del arreglo no debería ser hecha dentro de este método, por tanto tu **método loop** quedaría como:

```
static void loop(int[] array)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
   {
      Console.WriteLine($"Número {i + 1}: ");
      int num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      array[i] = num;
   }
}
```

Como ves este nuevo **método loop** cambió en su implementación, ahora no retorna ningún valor y solo recibe como parámetro el arreglo de números.

Entonces tu código original podría quedar como:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array1 = new int[15];
    int[] array2 = new int[15];
    int suma1 = 0, suma2 = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Introduce dos lista de 15 valores: ");
    Console.WriteLine("Introduce los datos de la lista 1: ");
    loop(array1);
    Console.WriteLine("Ahora introduce los datos de la lista 2:");
    loop(array2);
    suma1 = array1.Sum();
    suma2 = array2.Sum();

    if (suma1 > suma2) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"La suma de la lista 1 es mayor a la suma de la lista 2.");
    }
    else if (suma2 > suma1)
    { 
       Console.WriteLine($"La suma de la lista 2 es mayor a la suma de la lista 1.");
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Las sumas de la lista 1 y la lista 2 son iguales.")
    }
}
```

Aquí llamas al **método loop** para llenar ambos arreglos, y posteriormente obtendrías la suma de estos arreglos(bien podrías hacer un método cuya única responsabilidad sea calcular la suma de los elementos de un arreglo, yo no lo hice así pero es una buena idea). Después preguntarías si la suma de los elementos de la lista 1 son mayores a la suma de los elementos de la lista 2, si la suma de los elementos de la lista 2 son mayores a la suma de los elementos de la lista 1, o si ambas sumas son iguales.

Hacer que cada método o clase cumpla con el **principio de responsabilidad única** garantiza mayor legibilidad de código, mayor reutilización, facilidad de mantenimiento del código y muchos otros beneficios.